# CGContextAddArc counterclockwise instead of clockwise

Tags: ios, calayer, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I'm having an issue when drawing an arc inside of my drawing function inside of a CALayer subclass. The implementation for that drawing function is as follows:

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    CGFloat radius = MIN(center.x, center.y);

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

    CGContextAddArc(ctx, center.x, center.y, radius, DEG2RAD(0), DEG2RAD(90), YES);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

Nothing too groundbreaking here, but the weird thing is that it's drawing the arc counterclockwise even though I specified that it shoud be clockwise. Conversely, when I specify NO for the clockwise parameter, it draws the arc clockwise. I did some research into flipped coordinate systems and figured that might be what the issue here is, but I didn't want to just hardcode the opposite bool parameter of what I meant. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is indeed due to the flipped coordinate system of UIKit vs. Quartz. From the [docs for CGContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html):

> The clockwise parameter determines the direction in which the arc is created; the actual direction of the final path is dependent on the current transformation matrix of the graphics context. For example, on iOS, a UIView flips the Y-coordinate by scaling the Y values by -1. In a flipped coordinate system, specifying a clockwise arc results in a counterclockwise arc after the transformation is applied.

You can alleviate this in your code by using the transformation matrix to flip your context:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
```

You probably want to flip it back when you are finished with your drawing i.e.

```
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

// Draw...

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response and explanation! I tried adding the code you posted and it's now drawing clockwise as expected but instead of drawing one quadrant (the lower right quadrant of the circle as expected for a 0-90 degree range), it's drawing the 0-270 degree range clockwise. Any ideas why?

Comment: I just tried this, and it's drawing 3/4 of a circle from due east (0 degrees) clockwise to due north (90 degrees). If you want the lower-right quadrant of the circle, it should be from 0 degrees to 270 degrees (due south) clockwise. The clockwise parameter doesn't change how the angles are interpreted, only which "half" of the circle gets drawn.

Comment: Oh okay I think I understand why that is... by the flip transformation the 90 and 270 degree positions get swapped and the x gets left alone. Sorry about that.